# How can I lose weight? 13yr old

Tags: weight-loss, diet

I'm Emily. So, the past few months I noticed that I gained quite a bit of weight. I know why. I can't stop eating. I try but it's so hard. My diet and exercises only last for a day or two, then I'll just eat a whole tub of ice cream. Im ashamed of myself. I hate my body.

I'm on a diet right now, but the thing is I can't exercise. It's not because I'm lazy, please dont make fun of me, but I can't run. The doctor said Im not allowed. I have problems in my hips, legs and feet. I don't want to go into detail, jeez I dont even understand half the stuff that's wrong with me. I have to skip P.E in school and the only thing I can do is swimming and cycling.

I hate swimming and cycling hurts. But I'm still gonna try it. I think I'm just unfit, so I'll keep at cycling. My legs are so fat and I have rolls of fat on my belly. I am 5 ft and I weigh 103 pounds. Apparently that's underweight for some people but how come all my friends are like 90 pounds? Please  I hate it, I feel left out.

People are always talking about how they look and everything at school makes me feel really bad about myself. Thank you. (I made tons of mistakes in typing) Sorry if this is in the wrong catagory.

Comment: I'd suggest that you don't (only) hit the gym, but see a therapist very soon. It really sounds as if you are running straight into an eating disorder (if you're not there, yet). This kind of issues can get very severe and as a 13 yr old girl you are probably the number one risk-group for.

Comment: Losing-weight stuff is more about food plan than activilty (but it also matters a lot). Quick advice - do not eat white bread, junk food, avoid anything with sugar in it (sodas, juices, fruits, candys). But zero sodas are okay. Btw what diet plan you got?

Comment: Your BMI is around 19 - means - perfect. If you feel pain while running, cycling - talk with trainer at the gym - that is not normal, and you need help. Numbers, you've provided are OK, you should not feel pain in your joints. Without seeing you - we can only give general advices - talk with someone, better diet will help more then exercises...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're in a tough spot right now, but fight through it - this stage will pass.

The key thing is to be healthy - weight in and of itself isn't the key. To promote health, you'll need to control three things:

1. **Diet** - eat healthy food (fewer processed foods, junk food, soda, etc.). Portion control may be required - binge eating (like the tub of ice cream mentioned) isn't healthy.
2. **Physical activity** - if running/walking are out of the picture, then try moderate amounts of swimming and biking. If biking hurts, find a trainer or visit a bikeshop to find a bike setup that is comfortable for you. The key thing is to find some physical activity that you'll enjoy doing - it's hard to be consistent with activities you dislike
3. **Mental attitude** - find a way to keep positive outlook, it'll be hard to keep your motivation up if you're always down on yourself. There are as many different paths to a healthy attitude of life as there are people - for some, it's volunteering, for others, religion is a big help. In this case, no one other than you (and perhaps family or close friends) can decide what is the right way.

Comment: JW8 summed up well. Obesity in general has become a society problem, not simply personal, and solving it requires change on a collective, society level. I hope this helps you see that you're not alone. The reason JW8 listed diet first is because weight control is at least 70% about dietary control. Exercise is vital in keeping you healthy, but plays a smaller realistic role on weight control in the specific situation you mentioned. In light of that, research, learn & ask lots of questions about creating a good diet for yourself, and you must involve your entire family in it as well.

Comment: thank you so much! im trying to get healthier. it's actually going really well. im eating half of the junk food that i would normally eat, and im eating more fruit and veg. Im actually enjoying it. i already feel better

Comment: @twentyonephans, that's great! Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to hear about your hips and joints, I know there is pressure on you to look a certain way and in terms of confidence you would feel better and have more energy to take on the world if you lost those couple of extra kgs.

So your physical capabilities left aside, what can you do and what do you have control over??? The food you eat!!

80% of weight loss happens right in the kitchen, so even without exercise you can lose weight. Here are some tips that I would suggest:
Eat smaller portions more often
Eat more green veggies(they burn calories whilst eating)
Chicken and fish is still the best, less read meat.
Allow yourself a cheat day, where you can eat what you want, but get back to your new routine the very next day, see it as a reward for doing well.
Drink water, slowly and try for the 6-8 glasses a day (that's no lie)
Cut out sugar and fat from your 6 days of eating better but allow it back if that is your treat on day 7.

Just by following these broad rules, you will lose weight. Just remember doing something is better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I want to applaud your courage for being so forthcoming about your weight issue, as not many people are this brave. The first step in changing yourself is that you accept the need for change, which is exactly what you have done.
Now coming to the part about how to lose weight. It can be very challenging to workout when you are not supposed to do quite a few physical activities. But there are so many other fun things you can do, which will help you lose weight and which are not boring either. Do consult with your doctor and ask him/her about alternate physical activities for you. You could try aerobics, gymnastics, yoga, by learning it from a certified professional. Along with this, you probably want to meet a nutritionist as well. You will get great guidance about the foods which you can and should not eat. 
If you dedicate yourself to this, you are bound to get great results. I hope this answer was helpful. Here is wishing you good luck Emily!